Characterise Awk regex engine
I'm trying to implement a robust ere_parenthesize function which requires to accurately parse the bracket expressions of a user-provided ERE.
The difficult part is that the support for character classes [: :], equivalence classes [= =] and collating symbols [. .] in bracket expressions differs between Awk implementations while being critical for determining the termination of a bracket expression.

A simple example would be that /[[:punct:]]/ is equivalent to /[:[punct]]/ when Awk doesn't support [: :].

I brainstormed a few runtime checks that are not enough to fully characterize a regex engine (given the constraint that they shall not trigger a fatal error). Still, I ran them with multiple Awks/OSs and made a few assumptions in light of the results:

note: I'm still looking for implementatons that would invalidate the assumtion #1

An implementation that supports [= =] but doesn't support standard backslash-escape sequences within it always has the termination bug found here:


match("]", /[[=x=]?]/) == 0 (support for equivalence classes)

match("]", /[[=\t=]?]/) == 1 (no support for standard backslash-escape sequences within [= =])


implies:


match("]", /[[=x]?]/) == 1 (termination bug)



An implementation that supports [= =] and standard backslash-escape sequences within it does not have termination bugs:


match("]", /[[=x=]?]/) == 0 (support for equivalence classes)

match("\t", /[[=\t=]?]/) == 1 (support for standard backslash-escape sequences within [= =])


implies:


match("]", /[[=\t]]/) (crash)



An implementation that supports [: :] but doesn't support [= =] always has termination bugs:


match("1", /[[:xdigit:]]/) == 1 (support for character classes)

match("]", /[[=x=]?]/) == 1 (no support for equivalence classes)


implies:


match("]", /[[:xdigit]?]/) == 1 (termination bug)

match("]", /[[:abc:]?]/) == 1 (termination bug)

match("]", /[[::]?]/) == 1 (termination bug)

match("]", /[[:]?]/) == 1 (termination bug)





My question is about confirming/invalidating the above assumptions; could you provide the results of running the following code with the Awks/OSs that you have at hand?
BEGIN {
    ere_brackets_have_character_classes    =  match("1", /[[:xdigit:]]/)
    ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  = !match("]", /[[=x=]?]/)
    ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug =  match("]", /[[=\t=]?]/)

    print "ere_brackets_have_character_classes    :", ere_brackets_have_character_classes
    print "ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  :", ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes
    print "ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug :", ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug

    if (ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes) {
        if (ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug) {
            print "Assumption #1: expected output: 1"
            r = "[[=x]?]"
            print match("]", r)
        } else {
            print "Assumption #2: expected output: crash"
            r = "[[=\\t]]"            
            match("]", r)
        }
    } else if (ere_brackets_have_character_classes) {
        print "Assumption #3: expected output: 1"
        split("[[:xdigit]?] [[:abc:]?] [[::]?] [[:]?]", a, " ")
        print match("]", a[1]) && \
              match("]", a[2]) && \
              match("]", a[3]) && \
              match("]", a[4])
    }
    else {
        print "no expected output: nothing"
    }
}

note: Some Awks compile the EREs before running the code when they are provided as string constants or within / /; as a workaround I stored them in variables.

ASIDE
match("1", /[[:xdigit:]]/) should be locale independent, am I right?

FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p7:
awk version 20121220 (FreeBSD)
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 0
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 1
Assumption #3: expected output: 1
1

Ubuntu 22.04.4:
busybox → 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 1
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 0
Assumption #2: expected output: crash
awk: bad regex '[[=\t]]': Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=

original-awk (aka "nawk", "bwk awk", and "one true awk") → 2018-08-27-1
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 0
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 1
Assumption #3: expected output: 1
1

mawk → 1.3.4.20200120-3
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 0
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 1
Assumption #3: expected output: 1
mawk: run time error: regular expression compile failed (bad class -- [], [^] or [)
[[:xdigit]?]
    FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0

Debian 8.11:
mawk → 1.3.3-17
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 0
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 0
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 1
no expected output: nothing


$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.3.0, API 4.0, PMA Avon 8-g1, (GNU MPFR 4.2.1, GNU MP 6.3.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2023 Free Software Foundation.

------
awk --traditional -f script.awk
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 1
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 0
Assumption #2: expected output: crash
awk: cmd. line:18: fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[[=\t]]/

------
awk --posix -f script.awk
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 1
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 0
Assumption #2: expected output: crash
awk: cmd. line:18: fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[[=\t]]/

------
awk -f script.awk
ere_brackets_have_character_classes    : 1
ere_brackets_have_equivalence_classes  : 1
ere_brackets_have_backslash_escape_bug : 0
Assumption #2: expected output: crash
awk: cmd. line:18: fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[[=\t]]/

Regarding:

match("1", /[[:xdigit:]]/) should be locale independent, am I right?

That depends what you mean by locale independent. It's locale independent in as much as [:xdigit:] will match whichever characters are considered valid hex digits in your locale, but then that means it can match different characters in different locales which makes it's result given any specific input set locale dependent. So if there's some locale out there that uses the batman symbol to mean the hex digit 1 instead of the ascii character 1 then your match("1", /[[:xdigit:]]/) would fail to recognize it. If you want your code to be portable with respect to ascii input, you should set LC_ALL=C or LC_ALL=POSIX before it runs.

Thanks Ed, I only had GNU awk 4.2 for testing the code. So, if ˋ[:digit:]` is locale dependent, what good test could we use for determining that the character  classes are supported?

I just updated the end of my answer regarding that - set LC_ALL=C before running it. Unfortunately I'm not aware of anything equivalent you could do within your awk code.

In GNU awk, [:digit:] and [:xdigit:] don't seem to depend on the locale https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html , which feels weird for [:digit:]

Weird indeed. According to a post I came across at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26535950/1745001 [:digit:] could also include the characters ٠‎ through ٩ or ๐ to ၉.

Yes, [:digit:] might include other characters but GNU doesn't seem to care (I didn't test it as I don't have any of the locales required for that). Moving to the subject of a locale independent test for the character class support, there seems to exist 5 standard classes that are "special" https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01 ; for eg. a [:digit:] that doesn't include 0...9 should be hard to find

FWIW in case it's ever useful for your investigation of locales, I posted a script a while back at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481563/1745001 to dump which ASCII characters are recognized by which character classes in your locale.
